# how can I set kendo dropdownlist text programatically when using a template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I have this dropdownlist

```
        $("#rooms").kendoDropDownList({
            template: kendo.template($("#roomsListTemplate").html()),
            valueTemplate: kendo.template($("#roomsSelectTemplate").html()),
            filter: "contains",
            dataTextField: "room",
            dataValueField: "id",
            dataSource: roomsList,
            index: 0,
            select: onSelectRoom
        });
        var rooms = $("#rooms").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

that uses this template

```
            <script id="roomsSelectTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                <span class="roomName">
                #if (room != 'null' && room != '')  { #
                     #=room# 
                # } #
                #if (availability == 'roomOk')  { #
                    - Available
                # } #
                </span>
            </script>
```

Now I want to be able to set the dropdownlist text programatically. I'm trying with :

```
        rooms.text("Select a room...");
```

This works ok on another dropdownlist that has a template with only one value, but this one has two values (**room** and **availability**).

Firebug throws "ReferenceError: availability is not defined" so the problem is definitely that the template is expecting a value for **availabity**

I have tried

```
    rooms.text("Select a room...","Something here");
```

But same result and error message from Firebug...

You can see both behaviors here http://jsfiddle.net/pmeconi/jr2kgvsd/1/

Any ideas on how to make it work when there is more than one value on the template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will work with your setup , but you can use "optionLabel" property for your drop down, and then select 0 element.

Have a look at your fiddle which I modified slightly.

```
$("#rooms2").kendoDropDownList({
    template: kendo.template($("#roomsListTemplate2").html()),
    valueTemplate: kendo.template($("#roomsSelectTemplate2").html()),
    filter: "contains",
    dataTextField: "room",
    dataValueField: "id",
    optionLabel: "Select room",
    dataSource: roomsList,
    index: 0
});


$("#changeText2").click(function(e) {
    rooms2.select(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jr2kgvsd/2/

Comment: thanks Stefan, that almost solved my problem
ideally I want to be able to change the label itself programatically and although I can do it with your suggestion by adding this

`rooms2.options.optionLabel = "New text here...";`

I'm still not able to change the text on the dropdown itself

You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/pmeconi/uh5u4L0L/1/

Comment: Sorry I was away for the last three days. How about you use the setOptions function instead? rooms2.setOptions({optionLabel: "New text here..."});